# mobile css story image and ad image

Tags: html, css, image

So I have an interesting issue that has come up. Recently we put some ads on the mobile version of our site. The site loads stories and sometimes has images within the story that get rendered. On the mobile site, we have the following css applied:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

This works great and allows our story images to appear as they should. But what happens is, once we've added the ad source, they render images as well, and those images then appear in the same size ratio as the other images (eg: 200 x 300)

I need to figure out a way to apply the media screen css to only the article image and not all images that render on the page. Here's our block of code from a story:

```
            <div id="blogSingle" class="wrappedContent">
                <!-- Blog Meta -->


                <p class="listMeta">
                            <span class="listMetaDate"><span class="webFont">P</span> 04/24/2015 5:00:00</span>
                            <span class="listMetaAuthor">Newspaper Staff</span>
                </p>

                <h2>Story headline</h2>

                <figure class="articleimg">
                        <a href="article_1776425142222_1.jpg"><img style="float: right; position: relative; margin: 10px 0px 15px 10px;" src="article_1776425142222_1.jpg" alt="Image"></a>
                </figure>
                <p>content goes here</p>

            </div>
```

I apologize in advance, as CSS is not my strong suit. Could someone offer a bit of advice on how to apply the proper css for the article image?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .articleimg img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all different variations, but that one! I will accept the answer when I SO allows me!